# No such module 'SCSDKCreativeKit'

Tags: swift, cocoapods, snapchat

I believe the Snap Kit SDK may be faulty. I created a completely new iOS project, setup the Cocoapods workspace and then added:

```
pod 'SnapSDK'
```

With a sucesfull installation. I then as per the tutorial:

In my view controller added:

```
import SCSDKLoginKit
```

However I'm getting the error: No such module 'SCSDKLoginKit'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cocapods installation method seems to be bugged at the moment. Instead of using CocoaPods, use Carthage to install. This should fix the error, as it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download individual SDKs to add to your project separately. In your Podfile, specify which kit you want. Each can be used independently.

This resolved issue of **No such module 'SCSDKLoginKit'**

```
 pod 'SnapSDK', :subspecs => ['SCSDKLoginKit', 'SCSDKCreativeKit', 'SCSDKBitmojiKit']
```